# Python console error conditional statement

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm playing with the os module on python, namely the function which gives you access to the console, and I'm trying to create a sort-of Wi-Fi network sign in tool. This is all done on a Mac, and I'm using the `networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 "SSID" password`. I was wondering, when a password is wrong, if there was a way for python to respond to that, kind of like a try...except... statement.
Here's the current code:

```
import os
ssid = input("Please enter the network SSID \n")
password = input("Please enter the network password \n")
print ("Connecting to...")
print ("SSID: " + ssid)
print ("Password: " + password)
os.system("networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 \"" + ssid + "\" " + password)
```

Comment: Post your code so that we can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Change the Exception to catch the exception raised.

```
import os
success = False
while not success:
    ssid = input("Please enter the network SSID \n")
    password = input("Please enter the network password \n")
    print ("Connecting to...")
    print ("SSID: " + ssid)
    print ("Password: " + password)
    try:
        os.system("networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 \"" + ssid + "\" " + password)
        success = True
    except Exception as e:
        print("verification failed")
        print("Exception: {}".format(e))
```

Comment: The password error is "Error: -3900", so what would I put in place of Exception.

Comment: Please check the answer from @imolit to use subprocess to check response before usign `os`

Answer (score 0):

It seems `networksetup` does [not behave well](https://superuser.com/questions/656779/execute-bash-command-if-wireless-network-is-deleted), and returns 0 even on errors. This means you will have to parse the output from the program.

```
import subprocess
import sys

def networksetup(ssid, password):
    cmd = 'networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 "{}" {}'.format(ssid, password)
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return output

def main():
    ssid = input("Please enter the network SSID \n")
    password = input("Please enter the network password \n")
    print ("Connecting to...")
    print ("SSID: " + ssid)
    print ("Password: " + password)
    output = networksetup(ssid, password)
    if 'Error: -3900' in output:
        print("Password error: {}".format(output))
        sys.exit(1)  # remove this if you don't want to exit on error

if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```